# I cant use a python package even after installing it

Tags: python, macos, terminal

I want to install bullet,

```
pip3 install bullet
```

then run this script

```
from bullet import Bullet, Check, YesNo, Input
```

but I get this

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'bullet'
```

Whats happening?

EDIT:
I'm using python version 2.7.18

I'm running my script through a file like this:

```
python3 file.py
```

which python = `/usr/bin/python`

which pip3 = `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/bin/pip3`

Comment: 'pip3' (python 3 pip) and 'python version 2.' - does that fit?

Answer (score 1):

pip3 is the install command for Python 3 and python3 is the command to run a python program with the Python3 interpreter.

You have probably installed bullet to your Python 3 libraries so your Python 2.7.18 will never find the library.

Run Python 3.xx up instead of Python 2.xx

Answer (score 0):

1. As @MagnusO_O mentioned you can't use pip3 with python version 2. pip3 is the package manager for python version 3.
2. Your steps are fully correct. Try to verify that your package has been installed. For this run `python3 -m pip freeze` or `pip3 freeze`